# When a group homorphism must be $K$-linear

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I say a field $K$ is cool if every group homomorphism between to $K$-vector spaces is $K$-linear.

$\mathbb{Z}_p$ is cool because multiplication by a scalar is like an iterated sum.

$\mathbb{Q}$ is cool too. Lef $f$ be such a group homorphism. $$bf(\frac a b x)=f(\frac a b x)+\ldots +f(\frac a b x)=f(\frac a b x+\ldots+\frac a b x)=f(ax)$$
(the dots mean "$b$ times") and hence
$$f(\frac a b x)=\frac a b f(x).$$

The field of $p$-adic rationals are cool too (same argument).

$\mathbb{F}_4=\{0,1,a,a+1=a^2\}$ is not cool. The map
$$0\mapsto 0,1\mapsto 1,a\mapsto a+1,a+1\mapsto a$$
repsects sum but not multiplication by $a$.

$\mathbb{R}$ is not cool. Let $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_i,\ldots\}$ be an (uncountable) basis for $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. The map
$$(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_i,\ldots)\mapsto (\alpha_2,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_i,\ldots)$$
(swapping the first two components) is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear and so respects sum but it's not $\mathbb{R}$-linear because $x_3\mapsto x_3$ but $x_1\mapsto x_2\neq x_1$. The algebraic neither are cool by the same argument.

I wondered if cool fields have been studied before, and under which name! What's the pattern behind them?

For me the link between (and reason for coolness of) $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is that both are the fields of fractions of the only cyclic integral domains. Maybe coolness is hereditary and the $p$-adic rationals are hence naturally cool.

Comment: As an upgrade, you can look for the "cool" (commutative) rings $R$ such that for any two $R$-modules $M_1, M_2$, each homomorphism of additive groups $M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ is already $R$-linear. If I'm not mistaken, these are the epimorphic images of $\mathbb Z$, which includes all quotients and all localizations of $\mathbb Z$ (but also more: https://mathoverflow.net/a/110443/27465). The only fields among those are the $\mathbb Z/p$ and $\mathbb Q$, matching Alex Kruckman's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only cool fields are $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. So "cool field" is a synonym for "prime field".

You showed that the prime fields are cool. Now suppose $F$ is not a prime field. Let $k\subsetneq F$ be the prime subfield of $F$. Then $F$ is a $k$-vector space of dimension at least $2$, so it admits a nontrivial $k$-linear automorphism, which is an additive group automorphism, but which is not $F$-linear (since the only $F$-linear automorphism of $F$ is the identity).

In particular, the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not cool.

Comment: How is $\mathbb{Q}_p$ not cool? $p^k f(\frac a {p^k} x)=f(\frac a {p^k} x)+\ldots +f(\frac a {2^k} x)=f(\frac a {2^k} x+\ldots+\frac a {2^k} x)=f(ax)=f(x)+\ldots+f(x)=af(x)$ and so $f(\frac a {p^k} x)=\frac{a}{2^k}f(x)$.

Comment: @LucaT.Castrillón It seems you are confusing $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}] = \{\frac{a}{p^k}\mid a\in \mathbb{Z},k\in \mathbb{N}\}$. The latter is not a field (e.g. letting $q$ be a prime number not equal to $p$, $q$ is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]$). The elements of the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ look like formal Laurant series in the variable $p$.

Comment: I agree with you that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]$ is a "cool ring" in the sense of Torsten Schoeneberg's comment. In fact, it is a localization of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, and he points out that all quotients and all localizations of $\mathbb{Z}$ are "cool".